# Parsing Packets as they get received by a switch in Mininet

Tags: mininet, openflow, sdn, openvswitch

I have been reading about creating a learning switch in Mininet with different controllers (POX, Ryu ..etc). However, there are few things which are not clear to me and I hope to get help from here. My questions is:

I need to have control over the switch used in Mininet. Such that, I want to parse packets when they arrive to the switch from the controller. Is there any way to do this in Mininet?

Answer (score 0):

This task would be easy to do with OVS. If you must use Mininet, think link might help: https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/Introduction-to-Mininet#limits

I have not tried this personally with mininet, as I have multiple ovs's set up. Try modifying your mininet python code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing the functionality of the controllers that you mentioned. Mininet has a simply functionality and that is to define the network. It is useful but not powerful. The controller is what provides the functionality you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The is the function of packet in handler, parse the packet at the controller to get the specified features such as ip and mac addresses.